# Point to a hex stored in a string c++

Tags: c++, pointers, hex

I have this code (not really but it paints the picture)

```
uint32_t funcA(...)
{
  uint32_t len = -1;
  funcB((uint64_t)&len);
  return len;
}

void funcB(uint64_t arg0)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << arg0;
    std::string res(ss.str());

    std::string address = "0x00";
    address.append(res);
    // Now i got the exact memory address of len
    // Where do i go from here?
}
```

The in-values for the functions can't change but somehow i need to figure out how to manipulate the value of len that got passed in. If i have the memory address in a string is it possible to point to that address? If so how?
If not then how would i tackle this problem?

Comment: If you need to modify a parameter, then make the function take parameter by pointer or by reference. What you are doing here is not correct.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to be able to assign a value to len inside funcB. As i stated the functions can not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to take a detour through a string, and attaching `0x00` to a number doesn't magically turn it into an address.

The address of `len` (converted to `uint64_t`) is the argument that's being passed, so convert it back to a pointer:

```
auto len_address = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(arg0);
```

and then you can

```
*len_address = 5678;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next step is to convert back the string to a number: 
you can use [strtoull](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/)

```
uint64_t address1 = strtoull(address.c_str(),NULL,0);
```

Then take the result and assign to a pointer:

```
uint32_t* p = (uint32_t*)address1;
```

And finally you can set `*p` with a value:

```
*p = 0;
```